# Проблема с DockLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, java

Не создается компонента с использованием DockLayoutPanel, код примерно такой:

```
DockLayoutPanel panel = new DockLauoutPanel(Style.Unit.EM);
SimplePanel mainPanel = new SimplePanel();
panel.add(mainPanel);
SimplePanel northPanel = new SimplePanel();
panel.addNorth(northPanel, 3);
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что центральную панель нужно прикреплять последней. После её прикрепления вы больше не имеете возможности менять панели, имеющие dock layout. Там стоит assert: один - на проверку, что центральная панель еще не поставлена, если мы добавляем что-то еще; второй - на проверку, что добавлен хоть один боковой элемент, если пытаемся прикрепить центр (ошибки никуда не выводятся).

Правильный код будет выглядеть так:

```
DockLayoutPanel panel = new DockLauoutPanel(Style.Unit.EM);
SimplePanel mainPanel = new SimplePanel();
SimplePanel northPanel = new SimplePanel();
panel.addNorth(northPanel, 3);
panel.add(mainPanel);
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```